# How to use Kafka with the Azure and leverage Spring Cloud Stream or Spring Batch to push the messages into Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-batch, spring-cloud-stream

I was going through the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/kafka/apache-kafka-producer-consumer-api looks like there is no way if we can use the Spring Cloud Stream API with the Azure Kafka. Is this understanding?

If I've to implement the Kafka Producer and Consumer still I've to use the Kafka Client API only?

I am also looking to push and read messages into **Azure Kafka** by using the `Spring batch` Approach. Can I still use `KafkaItemReader` and `KafkaItemWriter` API provided by `Spring Batch` with the `Azure Kafka`? Does it works well?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Spring libraries (Stream and Batch); they use the same `kafka-clients` APIs.